# Vim is taking a really long time to open spelling suggestions

Tags: microsoft-windows, spell-checking

I have recently reinstalled vim and I noticed that the Spell checking is working very slowly. Whenever I do a `z=` on an incorrectly spelled word, Vim takes a good 4-5 seconds to show the spelling suggestions which is really really long. This used to happen almost instantly before.

It used to work fine before and I have no idea what happened. I checked this with bare vim too using `vim -u NONE` and it is still slow. So, I guess I can rule out this being an issue with my settings or with the plugins. And, Every thing else is behaving normally.

Any ideas on why this is happening and what can be do to speed this up? I am using the recent version of Vim for windows.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have several languages in `set spelllang?`, or maybe several methods in `set spellsuggest?`

Comment: I have `set spelllang=en` and `set spellsuggest=best`. I had the same setup even before but that was never slow.

Comment: Are you spell files `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/spell/*` (not clue where that is on windows, sorry) on the same drive?  Maybe on a network drive?

Comment: @grochmal, I think `$VIM_HOME/vim74/spell` is that directory. And, it is a local drive.

Comment: Wait, you say you used `vim -u NONE`, but that can still load plugins (from `/etc/vim` for example).  `vim -u NONE --noplugin` is safer as a check.

Comment: I am on Windows so I don't have `/etc/vim` or any other plugin directories. I keep them only in my `bundle` directory. Still I tried with `vim -u NONE --noplugin` and it is still the same. Takes atleast 3 secs to get the suggestions. It looks like reinstalling Vim is the only thing I can do.

Comment: this might depend on your word, which you are checking. Try with a different one

Comment: Which version of Vim are you running now? Do you know which version you were running previously? Does running the previous version fix the problem?

Comment: It was the same version. 7.4. I have kept the vim, vimfiles folder from the previous time and when I replaced it with that and the suggestions are loading fine now.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Its not for one word. It was that way for every word. The suggestions were taking a really long time.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop can  you updated the spellfile and your vim version? I think there was a [patch](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1064), that fixes that issue.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yeah that patch description looks right. But, what does single letter compounding mean? Does it mean spell file with just one character which I don't think was the case for me.

Comment: In case anyone is still running into similar problems in 2019, [this open issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4087) was very helpful for me and gives a comprehensive description of a flavor of this issue.